# Django: annotate count of replies by user through relation of field, and query optimization

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am struggling with this queryset for days, here's the model with three classes, `User`, `Category`, `Post`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    @property
    def most_reply_to(self):
        return self.post_setvalues('reply_to')\
            .annotate(reply_to_count=Count('user'))\
            .order_by('user')

    @property
    def most_replied_by(self):
        pass

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

    user = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    url = models.URLField()
    reply_to = models.URLField()
```

The `reply_to` filed in `Post` contains the information of user interactions, unfortunately it's not ForeignKey'ed to the Post model itself, but only to point to the `url` field of other post.

What I'd like to achieve here, is to annotate each user with:

- the counts of replies received, grouped by (source) user;
- the counts of replies given to, grouped by (target) user;

For the `most_reply_to` method, I have experimented as seen in my code, but the code only gave me count of replies to each individual post (from the user), not the **total** count of replies to each other users, I have lost  in the aggregate/annotate logic here.

For the `most_replied_by` method, I understand I need to start with the entire `Post.objects.all()` queryset, but I have no clue as how should I filter out  those that are replies to post of this (self user), then count the numbers grouped by (other) users.

Additionally, how should I annotate these two counts per category?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE 04-06-2021**

After spending few more hours, I came up these methods:

```
    @property
    def reply_to(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(url__in=self.post_set.values('reply_to'))\
            .values('nick__name')\
            .annotate(reply_to_count=Count('nick__name'))\
            .order_by('-reply_to_count')

    @property
    def replied_by(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(reply_to__in=self.post_set.values('url'))\
            .values('nick__name')\
            .annotate(replied_by_count=Count('nick__name'))\
            .order_by('-replied_by_count')
```

I didn't know that I can use queryset, i.e., `self.post_set`, as lookup parameters to filter another quesyset, i.e., `Post.objects.all()`, once I get to this point, it becomes straightforward.

Now my question becomes: these two queries appears to be awfully similar (only the `url` and `reply_to` fields swapped), but they do hit my database twice, also they take miserably long to execute on my millions of rows, is there a way to combine and optimize them?

Thanks again!